# WireShark/Fiddler like Network Capturing Tool for Windows Mobile 6

Tags: networking, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Is there any WireShark/Fiddler like Network Capturing Tool for Windows Mobile 6? I want to debug the network traffic of my mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Windows Mobile 6 supported a proxy for WiFi mode, which means you can capture its traffic similarly to capturing Windows Phone 7. See [this archived article](http://web.archive.org/web/20121026074003/http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-WinPhone).